# Can I have `backward reference` from `Pandoc`'s `link-citations=true` like `footnotebackref`?

Tags: cross-referencing, pandoc

`link-citations: true` can do this:
Once you click on any citation it will navigate to the end to a particular reference in your manuscript

but can't do navigate back and that's what I want.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: If you switch to `biblatex` you can use the option `backref=true`

Comment: Thanks. It seems work but not exact position. Is it normal?